# trying to mutiply results and getting error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, printing, integer

i'm trying to multiply the result "5,0" but nothing works, can someone explain what i'm doing wrong?

print result is "5,0 5,0 5,0 5,0 5,0 " i used .replace to remove "KM" from result.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
import re


#C:\Users\jefferson\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\webdriver_manager\drivers


servico = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
navegador = webdriver.Chrome(service=servico)
navegador.get("https://www.google.com.br/maps/dir//")


#digitar primeiro endereço

navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sb_ifc50"]/input').send_keys("Rimatur Transportes, Rodovia     Curitiba - Ponta Grossa Br-277, Km 2,1875 - Mossunguê, Curitiba - PR, 82305-100")

navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sb_ifc50"]/input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

#destino

navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sb_ifc51"]/input').send_keys("Av. Juscelino Kubitschek De     Oliveira - Ld, 2600 - Cidade Industrial De Curitiba, Curitiba - PR, 81260-900")

navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sb_ifc51"]/input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


def km():
    sleep(10)
    kmtotal=navegador.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div')
    km1 = kmtotal.text
    value = km1.replace('km', '')
    kmprint = value
    a = 5
    print(kmprint * a)
   #kmprint2 = int(float(kmprint))
 #  print(type(kmprint2))
km()`

print result >>> 5,0 5,0 5,0 5,0 5,0 `
```

Comment: The comma is the problem. It needs to be a dot: `value = km1.replace('km', '').replace(',', '.')`

Comment: @Flow

i do what u say, but the result still the same :(

Comment: That's weird, because I just did exactly that and it worked. How does your code look like now?

Comment: value = km1.replace('km', '').replace(',', '.').replace(' ', '')

print >>> 5.05.05.05.05.0

Comment: Ahhh. Okay, its still a string, but now `float(value)` is working (one of your following lines; sorry, I was assuming you would use it again). As povk explained you need to cast it to a numerical value in order use the value in calculations.

Comment: you know someway to do that?

Comment: `float(value)` does the type casting.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on [povk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8737235/povk)'s answer:

```
km1 = '5,0 km' # this is a string
value = km1.replace('km', '').replace(',', '.') # still a string
value_cast = float(value) # this is a float

value * 5
>>> '5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 '

value_cast * 5
>>> 25.0
```

If in your country decimals are typically written with a comma, you might find is useful to define a small helper function you can reuse later:

```
def to_float(value: str) -> float:
    # add more code if you also want to remove any letters/extract digits from a string
    return float(value.replace(',', '.'))
```

Comment: it works, i got the result 25.0, THANK YOU VERY VERY VERY MUCH

Answer (score 0):

`kmprint` is a string and there is no implicit casting in Python - you need to cast it to another type, e.g. `float` type to perform arithmetic calculations in Python after cleaning up the string. Otherwise, multiplication performed on a string will return the same string repeated `n` times.

Comment: good explanation brow, but you know someway to do that? i've tried to convert before, but nothing works :(